# Python TLS implementation with OCSP stapling

Tags: python, ssl, cryptography, tls1.3, ocsp

I was using [ssl](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) library for a project. But now when I want to implement OCSP stapling during the TLS (1.3) handshake, I found that there is no OCSP support in that library. What can be a good workaround? I would like to keep using the ssl library as I have already developed a significant amount of code and changing to a new library will be a tough job.

I think I have two options:

1. Use a new library that supports both TLS 1.3 and OSCP.
2. Modify the ssl library to add OCSP support.

Please let me know what you think. Thank you.

Comment: Look if `PyOpenSSL` provides it, it is an external library (not in core Python) that provides "ssl" features, and more than what is in core `ssl` module. Changing the core `ssl` Python library will probably not be an easy task.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, Thank you for your answer. I intend to check 'PyOpenSSL'.